# Rich Textbox and Data binding in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying bind data from database into rich textbox here is my code:

```
        DataTable NameTable = new DataTable("NameTable");
        NameTable.Columns.Add("PropertyNo");
        NameTable.Columns.Add("PropertyName");

        DataSet NameSet = new DataSet();
        NameSet.Tables.Add(NameTable);

        selectQry = new SqlCommand("SELECT PropertyNo, PropertyName FROM Property", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter DataAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQry);

        DataAdpt.Fill(NameSet, "NameTable");

        Binding NameBinding = new Binding("Text", NameSet, "NameTable.PropertyName");
        NameRtb.DataBindings.Add(NameBinding);
```

I am getting only last value. Can anyone help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible, I personally like to bind Data Tables to DatagridView's.

All you need to do is :-

Use a Binding Source, set its DataSource as the DataTable. You then set the Datasource fro the Datagridview as the Binding Source.

e.g below :-

//the DataGridView
DataGridView dgView = new DataGridView();

//BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

//set the BindingSource DataSource
bSource.DataSource = dTable;

//set the DataGridView DataSource
dgView.DataSource = bSource;